# Java API for xml type with JDBCthin driver

Tags: java, xml, api, driver, thin

I have been trying to access an xmlType column-table from my java application the whole day and all I found is functions oracle.xdb.XMLType. But sadly I can't use those functions since almost all start with the basig getOPAQUE function wich is not supported by thin driver. And I can not use oci driver in my application. So my question is if u can help me with a java api to access xmlType data from Oracle database table with a connection of JDBC thing driver connection. 
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=417030) thread. It specifically states that its not supported by the thin driver , but then suggests some workarounds.

Comment: tnx man this has been helpfull but i am preferring Oracles function instead.

Comment: To clarify more, though i liked the ideas in the thread above, mostly the one that suggests the use of ResultSet's getObject method with casting to XMLType. Yet I been suffering with exceptions like this; java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParseException. And i was referring what Oracle has to offer in this area, and to my surprise there are a bunch of functions that i can use. So I decided to use function like extractValue( ) from my xmlType doc and return the specific result as a String. But am still amazed that there is no specific API. tnx gain.
 I have decided to

Comment: @altsyset -- You're welcome. If this answer helped you, please remember to mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the checkbox next to it.